# 2 way binding with textarea ractive js

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, ractivejs

I am currently facing 2 issue, i am new to Ractive js
  1) As i am using `type="text/ractive"` and trying to use ckeditor for my `textarea`, which is not showing, if i remove `type="text/ractive"` then ckeditor is showing, how can i use both?

2) I am using Two way binding for `textarea` which seems to be working fine, but when `textarea` is replaced with `ckeditor textarea` plugin Two way binding doesn't work because changes are happening in `ckeditor textarea`, i think it updates the value based on some event as i am not changing `textarea` directly, it is being updated by ckeditor.

```
<script id="edit-template-quick" type="text/ractive">   
       // this is returning me the form
    drupal_render(drupal_get_form('xyz')); ?>
</script>

function xyz($form_id, $form_ids, $value) {  
  $form[$value] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#wysiwyg' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array(
      'value' => "{{ $value }}",
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}

    ractive = new Ractive({
       el: 'container-quick',
       template: '#edit-template-quick',

       data: {
                slides: json
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The purpose of using `type=text/ractive` or `type=text/html` is to keep the browser from attempting to parse the contents as javascript. It can be use to provide template:

```
<script id="edit-template-quick" type="text/ractive">   
    <p>hello {{place}}</p>
</script>
```

It looks like your intent is to have the server put the html into the script tag? I would check in the browser to see what is actually being sent, I suspect it's failing somewhere along the line. If you *are* wanting to run a function in the browser, then remove the `type` specification.

2) You could use a decorator, but I think a component works better to encapsulate the editor:

```
var CKEditor = Ractive.extend({
    template: '<textarea>{{{text}}}</textarea>',
    onrender() {
        var editor = this.editor = CKEDITOR.replace( this.find('textarea') );

        editor.on( 'change', evt => {
            this.set( 'text', evt.editor.getData() );
        });
    },
    onteardown() {
        this.editor.destroy();
    }
});
```

Then, assuming something like `components: { 'ck-editor': CKEditor }` in your setup, you can use it via:

```
<pre>{{doc}}</pre><ck-editor text="{{doc}}"></ck-editor>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/martypdx/jv15gjpr/ for example

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, in second scenario issue is `Two way binding` of Ractive component, textarea is getting updated properly from ckeditor as i could see changes, but values are not binding, i think because it will bind only on some kind of event on textarea like `change` or `on`.

Comment: > Values are not binding -

Not sure I follow, can you give example?

Comment: I am trying Two way binding `textarea` http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/two-way-binding, but it's not binding as it has ckeditor embeded.